# How to get smooth input for game in glut C++?

Tags: c++, glut

how do I get my C++ glut project to have smooth input? 
the only way I could get input was with a slight delay, which is annoying. I am new to C++ glut so pls help me.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <iostream>

GLboolean upPressed = false;

using namespace std;

void display();
void reshape(int,int);
void timer(int);
void keyboard_callback(int, int, int);
void SpecialKeysUp(int, int, int);
void update();

void init()
{
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
}

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE);

    glutInitWindowPosition(200, 100);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);

    glutCreateWindow("window");

    glutSpecialFunc(keyboard_callback);

    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutTimerFunc(0,timer,0);
    glutSpecialUpFunc(SpecialKeysUp);
    glutIdleFunc(update);
    init();

    glutMainLoop();
}

// sy is the first squares y position. no x value needed since the x value is static.
// also note that the "s" in sy stands for square, squarey_position
float x_position = 0.0;
float sy_position = -4.0;
int state = 1;
char input;

void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);

    glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);
    glVertex2f(x_position,1.0);
    glVertex2f(x_position,-1.0);
    glVertex2f(x_position+2.0,-1.0);
    glVertex2f(x_position+2.0,1.0);

    glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);
    glVertex2f(-8.0,sy_position);
    glVertex2f(-9.0,sy_position);
    glVertex2f(-9.0,sy_position+8.0);
    glVertex2f(-8.0,sy_position+8.0);

    glEnd();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void reshape(int w,int h)
{
    glViewport(0,0,(GLsizei)w,(GLsizei)h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(-10, 10, -10, 10);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

}

void timer(int)
{
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(1000/60,timer,0);

    switch(state)
    {
    case 1:
        if(x_position<8)
            x_position+=0.15;
        else
            state = -1;
        break;
    case -1:
        if(x_position>-10)
            x_position-=0.15;
        else
            state=1;
        break;
    }
}

void keyboard_callback(int key, int, int)
{
    if(GLUT_KEY_UP == key)
        upPressed = true;
}

void SpecialKeysUp(int key, int, int)
{
    if(GLUT_KEY_UP == key)
        upPressed = false;
}

void update()
{
//    glutPostRedisplay();
//    glutTimerFunc(1000/60,update,0);
    if(upPressed)
        sy_position+=0.15;
}
```

It is a ping pong game and currently the ball is working fine, however I am trying to get smooth input for the rectangle but the only way I could was with input delay.

I am new to glut C++ so pls help me

Comment: Ideally you would need to make another thread, but I'm afraid you're a beginner and it's hard for you to manage them

Comment: Don't see any code that is limiting your input to a reasonable speed.  Typically games will process input at a fixed amount, often at 60hz or 30hz doubling on a wait for VSync call.  Without that limitation, your input runs as fast as your computer, which causes no real control of the game.  By process input, I don't necessarily mean only accept input every 60hz, but you can buffer the input at interrupt time and then apply it in a more reasonable manner.  Or simpler, just read the keystate every VSync and use that.

Comment: Michael Dorgan I don't think you know what smooth input is. For example, when you go onto notepad and hold any key down(specifically a numeral or aphabetical key) it takes one input, has a delay, and then starts to spam the character your holding down. What I want is for the program to immediately spam inputs when I hold a key down, not put one input in, delay, and then start spamming characters. That's what smooth input is.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I figured out how to do it. The glutTimerFunc updates and resets every 1000/60 milliseconds so valuing a bool at "true" whilst the up key is pressed(with GLUT_KEY_UP) and then valuing a bool at "false" when the key is not pressed(with the SpecialUpFunc) makes for smoother input since the update function resets must faster than just holding the key down.